# HTML attribute not passing through to html from Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, string-interpolation

I'm sending this from Typescript

```
this.equationList = "<span id=\"Weight2\" class=\"weight\">W</span> = mg";
```

to HTML

```
<div [innerHTML]="equationList"></div>
```

All I get when I look at the element in the inspector is

```
<span class="weight">W</span> = mg
```

id="Weight2" doesn't make it through.  I've tried sending other attributes in the span.  Only class="weight" makes it through.

Comment: have you tried using angular expression `{{  }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a pipe like below :-

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml, SafeStyle, SafeScript, SafeUrl, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safe'
})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

 public transform(value: any, type: string): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
    switch (type) {
            case 'html': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
            case 'style': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
            case 'script': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
            case 'url': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
            case 'resourceUrl': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
            default: throw new Error(`Invalid safe type specified: ${type}`);
        }
  }
}
```

Use your innerHtml like :-

```
<div [innerHTML]="equationList|safe: 'html'"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the parent - child relationship? You can pass data from the child to the parent with @Outputs or you can pass data from the parent to the child with @Inputs.